# AltGr on Windows 10 - unable to type special characters

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, alt-code

- OS: Windows 10

  - Languages & Regions: Eng UK + Eng US + DEU
  - Keyboard: default input is DEU QWERTZ
  - Issue: <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + special characters `@[]}\~|` aren't printed

I've tried all the suggestions in the other two listed (related) questions (such as the RemoteDesktop, various key combinations, delete/reinstall drivers... ) but the only thing that currently works for me is to launch the virtual keyboard and type the characters from there. This also confirms, there are no 'physical' key issues with the HW.

Don't know where to go from here???
thx

Comment: I’m not quite sure I follow. The virtual keyboard working means there’s no software issue with the keyboard layout or anything. It doesn’t mean the physical keyboard is OK though…? // I suggest you try with some Live Linux to really rule out hardware issues.

Comment: sorry, I didn´t fully explain. I also have a Linux laptop, sharing the mouse & keyboard using Synergy so, I know the keyboard HW is OK

Comment: synergy config issue?  

Current config...  
Laptop 1: Linux Mint 19.03, Synergy (1.11.1) server, display lang=English UK, kbd layout=DEU  

Laptop 2: Windows 10, Synergy client, display lang= English UK, kbd layout=DEU  

Keyboard: Logitech MK330 combo wifi kbd & mouse, German vers.; connected to laptop 1 (synergy server) by mini dongle  

Laptop 1: AltGr+special chars - works as expected  
Laptop 2: AltGr+special chars - not printed (all other DE (umlaut) characters print OK)  

Note: Laptop 2 - laptop in-built keyboard, AltGr+special chars works as expected